# Content View Issue in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am trying to make horizontal uiScrollView. I have put buttons in its content view and have put the respective constraints as shown below
[image]

I have been able to scroll them properly but the buttons outside the visible area are not taking any touches as the content view width is not increasing with that of scrollview. Any Help

The white colour is of uiscrollview and that gray colour indicates ContentView[image]

Comment: The constraints on the above contentview is with respective to that of UiScrollView.

Comment: Can you please add screenshot of UI ?

Comment: If they are not visible, how do you touch?

Comment: i can see the buttons as i can scroll them horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to fix the Width of the `ContentView` because the scrolling area of `scroll view` is equal to `content view width or height` not scroll view width because width and height of scroll view is always equal to screen bounds for this give the `constant` value to `content view width`. Give constant `width` to your `ContentView` and height equal to `Scroll view`

Comment: have tried to do that but with no effect perhaps i have attached some wrong constraint to it.

Comment: remove the 'ContentView.width = width' Constraint